# How to do a logical 'or' of requirements in a single concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have the following case

```
template<typename Class>
concept has_member = requires (Class t)
{ 
    // How can I write only either of the following conditions be satisfied?
    {t.isInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;
    // or
    {t.canInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;
    // or
    // ... more conditions!
};

struct A {
    bool isInterface() const { return true; }
};

struct B {
    bool canInterface() const { return true; }
};

void foo(const has_member auto& A_or_B)
{
    // do something
}

int main() {
    foo(A{}); // should work
    foo(B{}); // should work
}
```

Like I mentioned in the comments, I would like to logically or the requirements (**in a single `concepts`**), so that the class A and B can be passed to the doSomething().

As per my knowledge, the the current concept is checking all the requirements, that means a logical and.
If I take it apart to different concepts everything works, but I would need more concepts to be written tosatify the intention.

Is it possoble to combne  into one? something like pseudocode

```
template<typename Class>
concept has_member = requires (Class t)
{ 
    {t.isInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>  ||  {t.canInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;
    // ... 
};
```

Comment: You might want to reword your question a little. Without context, it reads as a nonsensical sentence that many readers will skip over because they think it's someone who can barely speak English and it's not worth the hassle. Maybe ask something like, "How to do a logical 'or' of requirements in a single concept?"

Comment: @AikenDrum sorry for the bad English, yes. That is what I mean. Let me update it with your suggestion. Also feel free to edit if you find any mistakes.

Comment: Just so you know, your English was not actually bad. It's just that a reader without context will probably not recognize "or" as an operator instead of a part of the sentence. Once I realized that, the sentence made sense. You just needed to mark the word "or" as special, with quotes or allcaps or something, I don't know. But don't worry, your English seems fine. :)

Comment: I actually have a similar situation - to allow someone to use snake case or camel case method names e.g. `is_interface` and `isInterface`

Comment: It's also mentioned on CppReference - "Disjunctions": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Disjunctions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possoble to combine into one?

Yes, it is possible. You can write the conjunction of two `requires` as follows:

```
template<typename Class>
concept has_member = 
    requires (Class t) { {t.isInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>; }
    || //---> like this
    requires (Class t) { {t.canInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;};
// ... more conditions!
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7vsGh4G4P)

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you want to start building concepts, you should *start* with the point-of-use. That is, the place where you are going to use some template parameters for some purpose.

That means, you start with `foo`. How does `foo` "do something" with this interface? It can't be as simple as:

```
void foo(const has_member auto& A_or_B)
{
    A_or_B.isInterface();
}
```

That will be a compile error for some of the `has_member` objects. So you will need to do this:

```
void foo(const has_member auto& A_or_B)
{
    if constexpr(<stuff>)
      A_or_B.isInterface();
    else
      A_or_B.hasInterface();
}
```

Where `<stuff>` is some compile-time conditional check to see which actual interface the object has. You could spell out the `requires` clause, but that would be unnecessarily wordy. So just stick them in a concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_is_interface = requires (Class t)
{
  {t.isInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;
};

template<typename T>
concept has_can_interface = requires (Class t)
{
  {t.canInterface() }->std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

And now, your question answers itself:

```
template<typename Class>
concept has_member =
  (has_is_interface || has_can_interface) &&
  requires (Class t)
  { 
    // ... more conditions!
  };
```

---

That having been said, this design is generally wrongheaded. The reason is that it puts a lot of verbosity at the point of use.

What you *probably* want is to have a few free functions which can call the appropriate member interface:

```
bool do_is_interface(has_is_interface auto const& is_if)
{
  return is_if.is_interface();
}

bool do_is_interface(has_can_interface auto const& is_if)
{
  return is_if.can_interface();
}
```

And then your concept looks like:

```
template<typename Class>
concept has_member =
  requires (Class t)
  { 
    { do_is_interface(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>
    // ... more conditions!
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I know the `has_is_interface` and `has_can_interface` are possible in two different concepts and I know the pluses. However for the perticular set of classes(in real life) I do not require the distinction and therefore reusability doesn't matter.

Comment: BTW your answer doesn't discuss the actual question I asked.

Comment: @LernerCpp: I don't believe that it should be done in a single concept. There's basically no good reason to do it that way.

Comment: Sorry if the question is misleading. In actual case it is more convenient and make sense. It was hard for me to reduce the amount of code and ask the issue I had at one go. That might have mislead the actual intention. 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following concept form [stolen from the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/ranges#range.utility.conv.general-4)

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename Class>
concept has_member = requires (Class t) { 
  requires (requires { {  t.isInterface() } -> std::same_as<bool>; } ||
            requires { { t.canInterface() } -> std::same_as<bool>; }
            // add more functions
  );
};
```

which allows us to add different member functions directly in the `requires`-clause.

Comment: So this approach requires requires-requires-requires?

Comment: Compared to jejo's answer, this uses more requires and only gain is  `Class t` will be written once?